# Browser automatically refreshes and Home folder window opens

Tags: hardware, keyboard, events, evdev

I am facing a very strange problem. Out of the blue, my browser starts refreshing itself infinitely. My first guess was firefox is messing up. I installed chrome. But, it happens in chrome as well.

Other than that, sometimes my home folder automatically opens and keep opening itself infinitely. My next guess was Mouse is faulty. Replace the mouse - but same things.

This happens even if I remove my keyboard.

What can be the reason? This started happening after I installed Ubuntu 10.10 few days back. Earlier on windows, everything was working fine. So, I am a bit skeptical to assume that this is a hardware fault.

How to fix this problem?

**UPDATE:**

xev gives this kind of result:

> KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic
>   NO, window 0x4200001,
>       root 0xb8, subw 0x0, time 29897358, (237,791), root:(1252,842),
>       state 0x10, keycode 65 (keysym 0x20, space), same_screen YES,
>       XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (20) " "
>       XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (20) " "
>       XFilterEvent returns: False
>
> KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic
>   NO, window 0x4200001,
>       root 0xb8, subw 0x0, time 29897603, (237,791), root:(1252,842),
>       state 0x10, keycode 65 (keysym 0x20, space), same_screen YES,
>       XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (20) " "
>       XFilterEvent returns: False

Comment: What's your hardware?

Comment: Please, try to run your system in safe mode ( the other voice in the Boot Loader menu' ) then update us with results.

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and add `acpi=off` in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, after `quiet splash` inside of the quotes.

This fixed the issue in 10.10 desktop on a MSI Wind U100.